# How can I type the “@” symbol via VNC with a PC keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop

I'm connecting from a PC to a Mac via VNC. Now I want to enter some special characters like @. How can I do that?

[This](https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.1/misc/keyboard-mapping/) page didn't help. Other keyboard shortcuts I found out:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> = <kbd>cmd</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> = _

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> = ?

I'm using a German keyboard, but it seems that the English keyboard layout is used by VNC, because <kbd>y</kbd> is <kbd>z</kbd>. The clipboard also don't seem to work correctly ...

*Edit:*

**Physical keyboard layout PC**:
German keyboard layout “T1” according to DIN 2137-1:2012-06

**Logical keyboard layout PC**:
German

**VNC mapping**

**Logical keyboard layout Mac**:
German

**Physical keyboard layout Mac**:
German

Comment: This is a guess because of the mixture of keyboards but try shift-2 which is the normal UK/US Apple keyboard - the Windows keyboard tends to be a shift key near he return on the middle row

Comment: Shift + 2 leads to Ä. Is there a possibility to choose the keyboard layout? I didn't fully understand your last point.

Comment: Ok so not a mac keyboard - my comment was really based on US/UK PC and Mac keyboards swapping " and @  - Given your response try pressing the Ä key I would also try with and without shift and the key to the right of   Ä https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout

Comment: `Ä => r` and `Shift + Ä => F` and `# => §` and `Shift + # => ä`. Strange behavior ...

Comment: Have you tried the on screen keyboard?

Comment: @DavidAnderson: No. How can I select the @ here? I have enabled the software keyboard, but currently I don't know how to select the @ sign.

Comment: @testing please add the (logical) input source on the OS X side

Comment: @klanomath: What do you mean with input source? I'm typing with a PC keyboard (german layout) over VNC on a Mac.

Comment: Actually, I like the character view better.

Comment: @testing 1. physical keyboard layout PC -> 2. logical keyboard layout PC ~ 3. VNC -> 4. logical keyboard layout Mac  (-> 5. physical keyboard layout Mac) The last one is not relevant. 1: german 2: probably german 3. VNC mapping. The fourth one is missing.

Comment: @klanomath: The fourth is also German. But I think the VNC mapping uses the English keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the menu bar select System Preferences

Select the Keyboard Icon

Select the Keyboard tab

Select the "Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar" check box.

From the menu bar select either the Character or Keyboard viewer.

[image]

Comment: How do you select the @ sign with the keyboard viewer? The characters disappears after pressing the Alt key...

Comment: @testing: Can you hold down the Alt key on your "real" keyboard then select a key on the "virtual"l keyboard? I know I can do this, but I am not using VNC.

Comment: OK, while holding the Windows I can select the @ sign!